# How to click without using Xpath Selenium Python

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

How to click this item without using Xpath, ID, Linktext

best I would like to click after this attribute

`href="/tedsfasidnpopo/Jakpopo"`

```
 <td>
    <a id="STa_5" data-impr="False" href="/tedsfasidnpopo/Jakpopo" rel="5">
    <span class="newfile"><span class="">Jakkpopos12</span></span>
   </a> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dont want to use  Xpatch, ID, Linktex then use **css selector** to click

> td>a[ href='/tedsfasidnpopo/Jakpopo']

Induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"td>a[ href='/tedsfasidnpopo/Jakpopo'] "))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

**Edited**:

```
drewno='/tedsfasidnpopo/Jakpopo'
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"td>a[href='" + drewno + "'] "))).click()
```

OR

```
drewno='/tedsfasidnpopo/Jakpopo'
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"td>a[href='{}']".format(drewno)))).click()
```

Comment: I still have a newbie question I would like to put this value in a variable  "/tedsfasidnpopo/Jakpopo"  how it should look then I tried so variable is "drewno"
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"td>a[ href=drewno] "))).click()